# Python Lighting RGB LED based off blink speed

Tags: python, colors, raspberry-pi, led

Currently, my program accepts user input for blink length and delay between blinks and then loops through the lights a set amount of time. I have an RGB light also wired to the Pi and I would like it so that depending on how fast the lights are blinking, the RGB light will change color. As the program is now, the RGB light will stay red. I've tested the RGB light with a different program and it works fine so I'm fairly certain the error is in my code not the wiring. Thanks for the help!

```
# @kalenpw

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#use raspberry pi pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#GPIO output channels
GPIO.setup(31, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
#RGB Light
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

#Make LED blink 
def blink(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin,1)
    time.sleep(lightOnDuration)
    GPIO.output(pin,0)
    time.sleep(lightOffDuration)
    return

#turn on RGB led based off blink duration
def RGBTurnOn():
    #turn on red
    if lightOnDuration < .5:
        GPIO.output(15,1)
    #turn on green
    elif lightOnDuration < 2:
        GPIO.output(13,1)
    #turn on blue
    else:
        GPIO.output(11,1)

#Get number from user TODO fix
def getFloat(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = float(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error(01): please enter a number.")
            continue
        else:
            return userInput
            break

#Get integer from user TODO fix
def getInt(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error(02): please enter an integer.")
            continue
        else:
            return userInput
            break

#Starts LED loop
def StartLoop():
    RGBTurnOn()
    for i in range(0,numberOfCycles):
        blink(32)#5v green
        blink(38)#5v yellow
        blink(36)#5v blue
        blink(40)#5v red
        blink(37)#3v3 green
        blink(35)#3v3 yellow
        blink(33)#3v3 blue
        blink(31)#3v3 red

#Get light on & off durations
lightOnDuration = getFloat("How man seconds for blink length?\n")
lightOffDuration = getFloat("How many seconds do you want between blinks?\n")
cycleDuration = (lightOnDuration + lightOffDuration) *8
cycleDurationString = str(cycleDuration) + " second(s)."
numberOfCycles = getInt("Enter total number of cycles please.\n"
                       "Each cycle will take aproximately " + cycleDurationString +"\n")

StartLoop()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Pictures of wiring:

RGB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rulYL.jpg

LEDs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0zl0.jpg

LEFT red pin 31 gpio 6

LEFT blue pin 33 gpio 13

LEFT yellow pin 35 gpio 19

LEFT green pin 37 gpio 26

RIGHT red pin 40 gpio 21

RIGHT blue pin 36 gpio 16

RIGHT yellow pin 38 gpio 20

RIGHT green pin 32 gpio 12

rgb red pin pin 15 gpio 22

rgb green pin 13 gpio 27

rgb blue pin 11 gpio 17

Comment: It would be sufficient to just mention which I/O pins used for what LED i guess. I still dont see which io pins you used, Sorry.

Comment: @torxed LEFT red pin 31 gpio 6

LEFT blue pin 33 gpio 13

LEFT yellow pin 35 gpio 19

LEFT green pin 37 gpio 26

RIGHT red pin 40 gpio 21

RIGHT blue pin 36 gpio 16

RIGHT yellow pin 38 gpio 20

RIGHT green pin 32 gpio 12

rgb red pin pin 15 gpio 22

rgb green pin 13 gpio 27

rgb blue pin 11 gpio 17

Comment: Sweet, now this makes sense. I'm on a mobile otherwise I'd try to solve this myself and a suggestion is to add `# RED Left` after `GPIO.setup(31, GPIO.OUT)` etc. Makes for a easy reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your programming seems correct to me.

Just a wild guess:

From the pictures I see your RGB-LED is the common cathode type. Therefore, you should add a separate resistor for every led anode - not a single one for your cathode.
You didn't and maybe therefore, the red LED draws all available current (the state of the red GPIO is left unclear if green or blue are set to ON).

Try to set the GPIOs of not needed RGB-pins to OFF on startup or in your method.

```
def RGBTurnOn():
    GPIO.output(15,0)
    GPIO.output(13,0)
    GPIO.output(11,0)
    #turn on red
    if lightOnDuration < .5:
        GPIO.output(15,1)
    #turn on green
    elif lightOnDuration < 2:
        GPIO.output(13,1)
    #turn on blue
    else:
        GPIO.output(11,1)
```

Comment: The LED is a common anode like the one here http://www.mpja.com/5mm-Red-Green-Blue-Full-Color-LED-4-Lead-Common-Anode/productinfo/17137%20OP/ but you were correct about needing to turn them all off at the beginning of the method, it now works. Thanks!

Comment: Judging from your wiring and the fact that it works now (and didn't work before), I think you actually are using a common cathode led. Nevertheless - regardless of the type - each led pin should have it's own resistor. Otherwise you will run into trouble when trying to activate more than one color at once. Happy tinkering :-)